# Table taking up entire page

Tags: tables, page

I have a table in my article which is actually only about half page long but is taking up the full-page. There is supposed to be text before/after it, but it is all flowing to the next page as show below:
[image]

Below is the code that I am using to place the table:

```
\begin{table}
  \caption{Modeling results obtained from binary logistic regression}
  \label{tab:modelResults}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|p{0.43\textwidth}|l|l|l|}
\hline

//table text here..
    
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: you will have to upload your entire code as a MWE

Comment: As MWE try the following: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\caption{Modeling results obtained from binary logistic regression}
\label{tab:modelResults}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|p{0.43\textwidth}|l|l|l|}
\hline
1   & 2 & \lipsum[11]   & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}`. Please extend your code fragment to similar MWE (Minimal Working Example), which reproduce your problem.

Comment: I was able to solve it by replacing `\begin{table}` by `\begin{table}[h]`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

By default, full-width tables are only allowed at the top or on float pages, which obviously is the case for you. You can solve it by adding [!ht]

```
\begin{table}[!ht]
```